# creating a branch from a branch in svn

Tags: svn, branch

I want to create a branch from a certain branch. However, there is one sub-directory which has an older revision, and I need to get the latest revision of this sub-directory from another branch. We will still continue to work on the two branches plus the new one that we intend to create. I am wondering what is the best way to approach this.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create branch from branch (`svn co ...`) URL-URL
2. Merge "one sub-directory" from another branch to created on p.1 branch (in it's WC) and commit

or

1. Switch (WC) to branch, which must be main parent, update
2. cd to "one sub-directory which has an older revision", relocate it to "sub-directory from another branch", update
3. Create branch from WC (`svn co ...`) WC-URL